# Minimum threshold for Handegg hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I got the [Handegg hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/handegg) on Stack Overflow:

[image]

> Handegg
>   answer a question and get a score of 7 or more

I wonder why this minimum threshold is 7 only. Neither 5, nor 10. Its bit strange.

Was 7 randomly picked or is there any specific reason or logic behind it?

*P.S. (may be not related to subject):*

Seven is the most powerful magical number [based on centuries of mythology, science, and mathematics](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seven).

Comment: Because of the speciality of 7, it is also considered as lucky no. You already answered it in last part.

Comment: Well, as per me, yes.. As I am avid Harry Potter fan.. But was that really reason? I wonder.. :) @AnkitSharma

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unicorns are fairly lucky, but even they won't go for the [two-point conversion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handegg)<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchdown)</sup> unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: So that's an unicorn on the helmet? Looks like a blue version of [Peppa Pig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppa_Pig).

Answer (score 0):

Some historical background on *hangegg* dating back to 1909 letter to *The New York Times* can be found in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/215404/2085).

Additionally, Jon Ericson reveals in [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215399/what-s-a-handegg#comment458363_215402) that the included image was the exact one that gave rise to the hat’s name.

Comment: Comments are volatile and can get deleted without a trace, better quote relevant part here which explains why 7 was chosen.